# Service stack and Mocking, any tutorials?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, moq, servicestack

I am currently evaluating ServiceStack (to create rest based services in .Net). One of the areas of interest is the testing side. My rest service will have a number of app services injected in (currently using Autofac). What I need is a mechanism to test the rest layer and define expectations on my app layer (via MOQ), so I am not doing integration tests but unit testing this layer?

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [ServiceStack Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) is just like any normal C# Service class and can be mocked in exactly the same way like any other class. The minimum dependency for a ServiceStack Service is implementing the dependency-free `IService` interface marker and where any service just accepts a Request DTO and returns any object.

One way to Unit test ServiceStack services is to use the DirectServiceClient as [seen in this example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Tests/WebServicesTests.cs#L82), a benefit of this is that it lets you use the same Unit Test as an integration test - testing all the different XML, JSON, JSV and SOAP endpoints.

Otherwise you can unit test and Mock it like any other class, e.g:

```
var service = new TestService {
   MyDependency = new Mock<IMyDependency>().Object
};
var response = service.Get(new Test { Id = 1 });
Assert.That(response.Result, Is.EqualTo("Hello, 1"));
```

Comment: @Thanks. I think we will go servicestack for our new project. Great work.

Comment: When I mock services this way filter attributes don't seem to be triggered, is that expected behaviour?

Comment: When you Mock the `IService<TRequest>` you just using this to isolate the dependencies. All of the filter attributes depend on more of the stack running (i.e. setup/configuration/initialization specified in your AppHost class). If you need to test code in the filter attributes then the attribute classes should be tested independently.

Comment: I don't understand why ServiceStack wasn't designed via TDD in the first place; we wouldn't be having this kind of discussion as there would already be 100% code coverage, a crap load of tests to check out as well as mocks.  It's disappointing to our craft IMO that people are still not test driven.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict It's disappointing that people in our craft think their tech processes should be blindly imposed on every software project (and not where it actually yields a benefit) despite only a fraction of all software uses processes-driven cult-practices like TDD. We prefer Test After, especially. when designing Services APIs which we [take great care thinking about when designing services](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229/85785) which would not benefit for the bottom-up approach of TDD design.

Comment: retracted my statements, it's not worth a war...but I do disagree.

Comment: btw, thanks though for the link it gives me the thinking behind ServiceStack in terms of design

Comment: np :) retracted my orphaned response as well.