# ServiceStack REST API Design

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, servicestack

I'm starting to play around with ServiceStack and I'm enjoying it so far but I'm thinking my design is flawed from the get go.  Essentially, I have a MSSQL database which I'm accessing via NHibernate.  My confusion is coming about due to exactly what structure my request / response DTOs & services should take.

I have my NHibernate mapping in a separate project under MyProject.Common.Models which contains a "Client" class like so:

```
namespace MyProject.Common.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        public virtual int ClientID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Acronym { get; set; }
        public virtual string Website { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientMap : ClassMap<Client>
    {   
        public ClientMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.ClientID, "ClientID").GeneratedBy.Identity();

            Map(x => x.Name, "Name");
            Map(x => x.Acronym, "Acronym");
            Map(x => x.Website, "Website");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to provide the client the ability to CRUD a single client, as well as displaying a list of all clients.  So far, I've designed my single client request like so:

```
[Route("/clients/{Id}", "GET")]
public class ClientRequest : IReturn<ClientResponse>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClientResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public MyProject.Common.Models.Client Client { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    public ClientResponse()
    {
        this.ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
    }
}
```

Which as you can see is simply returning my model class to the client.  With this sort of design, I'm completely at a loss of how to properly POST a new client, or UPDATE an existing client.  Also, if I wanted to return a list of all clients, I'm currently using the following request/response DTOs:

```
[Route("/clients", "GET")]
public class ClientsRequest : IReturn<ClientsResponse>
{

}
public class ClientsResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public List<MyProject.Common.Models.Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    public ClientsResponse()
    {
        this.ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
    }
}
```

With a service like so:

```
public ClientsResponse Get(ClientsRequest request)
{
    var result = currentSession.Query<Chronologic.Eve.Common.Models.Client>().ToList();

    if (result == null)
        throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new ArgumentException("No clients exist"));

    return new ClientsResponse
    {
        Clients = result
    };
}
```

Which works, though I feel like this is also not the best way to achieve what I am attempting to do, and gives me an ugly metadata page showing like so:

[image: Ugly ServiceStack metadata]

I feel like I'm overlooking quite simple with this design, and if anyone could suggest to me how to streamline the design it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out these earlier posts which will help with API design with ServiceStack:

- [Designing a REST API with ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785)
- [How to design a message-based API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229/85785)
- [The importance of DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369736/85785)

Rather than re-hash any of the content contained above, I'll just rewrite it how I'd do it.

You don't need a `ResponseStatus` property so your services can return clean DTOs.

```
[Route("/clients", "GET")]
public class AllClients : IReturn<List<Client>> {}

[Route("/clients/{Id}", "GET")]
public class GetClient : IReturn<Client>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

The service implementation should be straight forward based on the above Request DTOs.

With the above API, your C# client call sites now look like:

```
List<Client> clients = service.Get(new AllClients());

Client client = service.Get(new GetClient { Id = id });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Demis!  I feel like this is a completely different way of doing this since I last played around with SS around the beginning of last year.

Comment: Yep, the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) has allowed for a lot more freedom which is always good :)