# How do I map multiple Request DTOs to a single Route

Tags: c#, rest, url-routing, servicestack, dto

I have been experimenting with the [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) framework to develop a simple REST API. I am having troubles trying to define the Routes properly to handle the different URLs I desire.

I have a simple DomainModel class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // unique
    public string Email { get; set; } // not unique

    // some other properties and business logic
}
```

I would like to create a REST service which responds to HTTP requests to the following URLs:

- `/students`

  - GET returns all students
- `/students/123`

  - GET returns student with Id = 123
- `/students?id=123`

  - GET returns student with Id = 123
- `/students?email=foo@example.com`

  - GET returns all students with matching Email

I have tried using the following Request DTOs to accomplish this:

```
[Route("/students", "GET")]
public class GetAllStudents : IReturn<StudentList>
{
}

[Route("/students", "GET")] // I want this to be for /students?Id=
[Route("/students/{Id}", "GET")]
public class GetStudentById : IReturn<Student>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Route("/students", "GET")] // I want this to be for /students?Email=
public class GetStudentsByEmail : IReturn<StudentList>
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I am only trying to use two different Response DTOs:

```
public class StudentList : List<Student>
{
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** This Reponse DTO `Student` class is separate than my DomainModel class; they are in different namespaces.

Unfortunately, when I try to use these routes, every request to `/students?<anything>` ends up returning all students. The only Route that does work is if I make a GET request to `/students/123`, then I get back Student with Id 123. I assume this isn't working because I am re-using the `"/students"` Route definition for multiple Request DTOs.

I have been reading through the ServiceStack [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki) and [examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples) but I can not figure out how to accomplish what I am attempting. The most detailed documentation I can find about advanced routing is the ["Smart Routing" section of the "New API" page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API#smart-routing) but it doesn't really address this situation either.

How can I re-use the same Route definition for mulitple Request DTOs?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that the way you want. Might I suggest the route `/student/{Id}` as an alternative?

Comment: @rossipedia Even if I get rid of the `/students?id=123` route, I still have the problem of duplicate route definitions on `GetAllStudents` and `GetStudentsByEmail`. Honestly, I don't need that  `?id=` route but getting rid of it won't get me any further. Maybe I am misunderstanding your suggestion? Can you provide more detail in an answer?

Comment: See @mythz's answer below. He explains it much better than I can :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having `ByXXX` suffixes on your Request DTOs is a code-smell in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) who wants to encourage the design of message-based coarse-grained interfaces. Please see this earlier answer on [How to design a Message-Based API with ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927475/servicestack-request-dto-design/15941229#15941229) and why you should group services by **response types** and **call semantics**

In this case you have a service doing a `Get` on a **Unique Id** returning a **single Student** and you also wish to have a `Search` on **Email** which returns multiple Students. So in this case I would have the following services:

```
[Route("/students/{Id}")]
public GetStudent : IReturn<Student>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Which would handle just `/students/123`.

```
[Route("/students")]
public FindStudents : IReturn<List<Student>>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Which can be used to handle:

- `/students`
- `/students?id=123`                        //but returns `List<Student>` instead
- `/students?email=foo@example.com`
- `/students?id=123&email=foo@example.com`
- etc

Although I personally wouldn't include an `Id` here since it's a **Get** instead of a **Filter**.

Comment: I was doing this approach at first, based on your answer in that link. I didn't like how I needed a bunch of `if` logic in my Service method to determine what the user was searching with. For example, if I also wanted to add `Birthday` to my `FindStudents` RequestDTO, then my Service method needs to do this logic: *"is Id set? is Email set? is Birthday set? what if Birthday doesn't match Id? etc."* I was trying to keep smaller, more focused service methods like `Get(StudentsByEmail request)` but I may be trying to 'fight the framework' here, which I don't want to do. I will experiment more...

Comment: @JesseWebb Note the if logic should be what you're using to build-up an internal query or filter so the same service can be called with any combination of filters.