# Service Stack Route for a collection field for a service

Tags: routes, servicestack

I have a service for Employee with a DTO

```
[Route("/employee/{id}", "GET PUT DELETE")]
[Route("/employees", "POST")]
public class Employee : Person
{
    public Employee() : base() { 
        this.dependents = new List<Dependent>();
    }
    public List<Dependent> dependents { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to understand how to handle the case where I want to just return the dependents collection.  I would expect the url to be /employee/{id}/dependents.  Being new to ServiceStack I am having a hard time figure how to map that to a service handler within my EmployeeService.  Much Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to understand how to handle the case where I want to just
>   return the dependents collection. I would expect the url to be
>   /employee/{id}/dependents

First you need to provide a route that matches the url you want:

```
[Route("/employee/{id}/dependents")]
public class Employee : IReturn<List<Dependent>>
{
    public Employee() { 
        this.dependents = new List<Dependent>();
    }

    public List<Dependent> dependents { get; set; }
}
```

I would also encourage you [not to use inheritance in DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368257/servicestack-new-service-side-by-side-asp-net-mvc-website/15369736#15369736) as it hides the intent and declarative structure of your services.

Your service implementation should be pretty straight forward:

```
public class EmployeeService : Service
{
    public List<Dependent> Get(Employee request)
    {
        return request.dependents; //just return the dependents collection?
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess my lack of understanding arises because EmployeeService already has a Get method for a singular Employee:

        [Route("/employee/{id}", "GET PUT DELETE")]
    [Route("/employees", "POST")]
    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public Employee() : base() { 
            this.dependents = new List<Dependent>();
        }
        public List<Dependent> dependents { get; set; }

    }

Comment: Thanks again.  I love servicestack.  I followed up my question with some clarification in my previous comment.  Since there already is a Get method for an Employee object I cannot use Get(Employee rewquest).  If I change the method name to something besides Get the routing does not match and I get a "Not Found" on the resource.

Comment: The **Get** name requirement is so it matches the **HTTP Verb** you wish to handle. See the [New Api](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) for more info.

Comment: I have looked through the New Api and a bunch of the sample apps.  If I want to have a service to match GET Verb for returning the Employee Object and also need to match another Method to GET Verb for Employee.Dependents do I have to have a different Service for EmployeeDependents?

Comment: If you want 2 different services returning 2 different responses, you should have 2 Request DTOs. See the answers on [recommended API Structure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15235822/85785) and [How to design a Message-based API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229/85785) for some more examples.