# Questions about naming of types in ServiceStack-based services

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I'm starting to use ServiceStack to implement a web service API. I'm trying to follow the examples and best-practices as much as possible, but sometimes this is not that easy (it seems that many samples are not yet updated to follow the [new API design](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API)).

What I currently have is something like this:

- an assembly named `MyApp.ServiceInterface` containing the implementation of the services/methods
- an assembly named `MyApp.ServiceModel` containing the request and response types and the DTOs

In the `MyApp.ServiceModel` assembly, I have for example:

```
namespace MyApp.ServiceModel
{
    public abstract class ResponseBase
    {
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } // for error handling
    }

    [Route("/products/{Id}")]   // GET: products/123
    [Route("/products")]        // GET: products?Name=...
    public class ProductRequest : IReturn<ProductResponse>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductResponse : ResponseBase
    {
        public Types.Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyApp.ServiceModel.Types
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Questions:

- I have seen different ways of how to name the request types (e.g. `GetProduct`, `ProductRequest` or just `Product`). What is the recommended approach?
- Does the naming somehow depend on whether the service is a REST-service or not?
- Would it be a good idea to put the request and response types into seperate (sub-)namespaces (e.g. `MyApp.ServiceModel.Requests` and `MyApp.ServiceModel.Responses`)?
- Why is the assembly containing the implementations named `ServiceInterface` (wouldn't `ServiceImplementation` fit better)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API design is subjective so there's no recommended approach. Although I personally [dislike appending 'Request' suffix](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/servicestack/cooDKwyIGKk/cBTKCMOri74J) on my Request DTOs since its effectively your Web Service Contract. I also dislike the use of inheritance in Service Models for trying to DRY properties which hides intent in your [Service Layer which is your most important contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368257/servicestack-new-service-side-by-side-asp-net-mvc-website/15369736#15369736).

The name of the Request DTOs doesn't affect REST Apis with custom routes since there's no externally visible difference with different Request DTO's using the same custom route. Although it does affect the surface area when using the [end-to-end typed clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client) since it forms the visible part of your typed API.

Here are a couple of answers which describe my preferences of how I would design service APIs:

- [Designing a REST-ful service with ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231537/recommended-servicestack-api-structure/15235822#15235822)
- [How to design a Message-Based API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927475/servicestack-request-dto-design/15941229#15941229)

C# Namespaces in DTOs have no visible effect on your API. In ServiceStack Request DTOs map 1:1 with your Service so they **must be unique** which, if you append a 'Response' suffix for your Response DTOs, they will end up being unique as well. As a goal I ensure all my DTOs, both operations and types, are uniquely named so it doesn't matter what their physical layout is. As a convention I now like to place my operation DTOs (i.e. Request / Response) on the top-level of the Service Model assembly, with the Request / Response DTO in the same C# .cs file whilst all other 'DTO Types' in a Types folder, e.g:

- /Products.cs (holds GetProduct and ProductResponse DTOs)
- /Types/Product.cs

It's called **Service Interface** since it matches the Gateway Service pattern where your client is called a **Client Gateway** whilst your Server is called the **Service Interface**. The use of `Interface` here means service entry point and not C# Interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have to read and digest all that information, and might then come back with some additional questions.

Comment: some comments and follow-up questions: I'm using end-to-end typed clients - that's why I care a clean naming of the DTOs. I think I'll go with GetProduct/GetProducts, ProductResponse/ProductsResponse and Types.Product. Part of the confusion was caused by the "error-handling" wiki page, which says to use GetProduct/GetProductResponse and that the response should have a ResponseStatus property (that's why I introduced a Response base-class). Should that page be updated? Also what is the rationale for having Response classes at all (why not simply returning a Product or List<Product>?

Comment: Sorry this is not well suited for a continued discussion. Should I post this to the mailing list / google group?

Comment: @M4N If you want to support SOAP endpoints (or be able to control the DTO used for Error Responses) you should continue to use the `Response` suffix. It was also a good convention to be able to infer the Response DTO w/o reading API docs - although marking Request DTOs with `IReturn<T>` is now a better and more typed/explicit approach. With the release of the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) you're now able to return *clean responses* like `List<Product>` and still marshal exceptions to typed clients (which uses the generic ErrorResponse DTO instead).

Comment: @M4N Any new and/or more specific questions should be asked as a new Question on StackOverflow.

Comment: whatever you do just keep the names unique. I joined a team in which their entities, response and request are same name and they distinguish between them by name space. You cannot imaging after a while it becomes horrible.