# How can I migrate my WCF services to ServiceStack API?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, wcf, migration, servicestack

Currently we are using the WCF services in C# as a web services and we want to migrate it to Service Stack Web API. So what is the best option to migrate it to Service Stack API..?

We are using WCF + SQL Server as a database.

What is the best combinations for ServiceStack + SQL Server to faster the APIs?

Any suggestion will be grateful..

Answer (score 0):

### [ServiceStack and WCF are fundamentally different](http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack)

There's no automated migration tool for converting WCF Services -> ServiceStack as they don't share any of the same libraries and have a [fundamentally different approaches for developing web services](http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack). However you should be able to re-use a lot of your DTO's and custom web services implementation logic that don't contain references to WCF libraries.

### [Learn how to create message-based Services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229/85785)

I would first start with going through how to developer message-based services with ServiceStack and how it contrasts with WCF-style Web Services at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229/85785

### Porting approach

If you have an existing WCF Service you should be able to extract the WCF Services implementation and port them to ServiceStack Services whilst being able to re-use a lot of your existing WCF DTO's, existing ORM logic and impl where you can registering any other dependencies you might have in [ServiceStack's IOC](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container).

### [Switching to OrmLite SqlServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)

If you prefer you may also want to consider switching to [ServiceStack's OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) which provides a nice light, typed SQL and LINQ-like API for accessing the most popular RDBMS's including Sql Server which you can register with a single line in your `AppHost.Configure()`:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
```

With just this single line of registration above you can now connect with your SqlServer database using the ADO.NET connection available at `base.Db`, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        return base.Db.Select<Poco>();
    }
}
```

### [Take advantage of AutoQuery's rich data-driven Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query)

This will also let you take advantage of [rich querying functionality in AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) to quickly develop data-driven services.