# Auto Query search

Tags: servicestack

How can I do an auto query with "or" operation like -
http://localhost/rockstars/first_name=Mike**OR**last_name=Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Section on [changing AutoQuery Behavior](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#changing-querying-behavior) where you can change the behavior of every field by annotating Services with `[Query(QueryTerm.Or)]`, e.g:

```
[Query(QueryTerm.Or)]
public class QueryRockstars : QueryBase<Rockstar> {}
```

Otherwise if you only want to some of the fields to have "OR" behavior you can decorate them individually with:

```
public class QueryRockstars : QueryBase<Rockstar>
{
    [QueryField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [QueryField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

However from a Services design POV applying different behavior is not recommended since ideally each of the [fields should have the same semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229/85785).

With the above Request DTO's you can now query it with:

```
/rockstars?FirstName=Mike&LastName=Smith
```

Comment: I tried the example you gave above but when I run the query like this - http://localhost/rockstars/first_name=Mikeorlast_name=Smith
it gives "0" result set even though data is present

Comment: just "&" in between ?

Comment: I tried 
public class QueryRockstars : QueryBase<Rockstar>
{
    [QueryField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [QueryField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

but this /rockstars?FirstName=Mike&LastName=Smith still give "0" result set

Comment: @SMV I've just [added a test for this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b84f9848f5a9aea82c650be83497e5e05fb24c04) which works as advertised.