# How DTO does not pollute your web services in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, dto

I am new in servicestack. I am reading [Servicestack Wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Why-Servicestack) and found this statement "your DTO's define everything Service Stack does not pollute your web services with any additional custom artefacts or markup." Please let me know how DTO is work in serviceStack so that it is not pollute web service?

Comment: Please take a look at first answer at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927475/servicestack-request-dto-design
hope it help you

Comment: I understood how to used  Request DTO in servicestack service. I have confusion on this line "web services with any additional custom artefacts or markup.". Which any additional custom artefacts this statement is talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ServiceStack you can use clean, unannotated POCO's to define your Services Contract (i.e. Request and Response DTO's). You also don't need any custom build steps or generated proxies to be able to call your Service as you're able to re-use the same DTO's you defined the Service with on the Client using any of ServiceStack's [Generic .NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) to provide an end-to-end Typed API without code-gen or custom build steps.

See the [Customer REST Example on the Home page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/#calling-the-above-rest-service-from-any-cnet-client) and it's [stand-alone Integration Test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/CustomerRestExample.cs) as an example.