# How to handle calling more specific routes based on a list of clubs returned in the client?

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

Suppose I have a list of clubs that a customer can belong to. I have a `FindClubs` route that will return all of the clubs that a customer could sign up for. I also have a `FindCustomerClubs` route that given a `CustomerId` will return all of the clubs that this particular customer belongs to.

What I'm not sure how to structure, however, are clubs that require/have additional information about the customer. For example, say I have a Birthday Club that requires the names and birthdays of the customer's children to join. It seems like that should be another more specific route, like `/clubs/birthday`. For clients that want to not only get a list of the clubs a customer has joined, but the additional information for each club to display, like children's birthdays, how do I structure this?

I found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/D8hcApC0mfI) that doesn't recommend HATEOS. I can understand that clients will not automagically get all sorts of new data and behavior. They need to know to call the more specific route to get it. However, is it wrong for the client to have to know that `ClubId` 123 is the Birthday Club and so if they want the birthdays they need to call the birthday route? Or is there another recommended way to avoid the tight coupling of IDs or descriptions to other routes? I'd hate to see all of the client apps needing a switch statement to perform another lookup based on the ClubIds returned for if that number changes everything will become chaos.

```
[Route("/clubs", "GET", Summary = Summary.FindClubs)]
public class FindClubs : IReturn<List<CustomerClub>> { }

public class CustomerClub
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
}

[Route("/customers/{" + nameof(CustomerId) + "}/clubs", "GET", Summary = Summary.FindCustomerClubs)]
public class FindCustomerClubs : IReturn<List<CustomerClub>>
{
    [ApiMember(Description = Description.CustomerId)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I'd recommend designing [coarse-grained message-based APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941229/85785) where I'd have different Services returning data for each aggregate root which I'd model after their client usage, e.g if clients need to find a Customers birthdays and which clubs they're members of I'd return them in the same Customer Service, e.g:

```
[Route("/customer/{Id}", "GET")]
public class GetCustomer : IReturn<GetCustomerResponse>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class GetCustomerResponse
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public List<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally Services should be self-describing so instead of just returning a List of ClubIds integers, I'd return the whole Club data model.

If an entire Club contains too much Info then I'd return a new DTO with just the info the client needs, e.g if they only need to display the name of the Clubs the customer is a member of, I'd create a separate DTO like:

```
public class ClubSummary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GetCustomerResponse
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public List<ClubSummary> Clubs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. But since DTOs can't/shouldn't use inheritance, how would I handle clubs? In an OOP sense, my business logic layer might have `Club` and `BirthdayClub : Club` where club has basic attributes like Id, Name, JoinDate and BirthdayClub has additional fields like ChildrenBirthdays. How does this fit into your example above?

Comment: @Connor My preference is to not use inheritance in data models either, but if you do you can populate a DTO with flattened properties that includes a Type to capture its Type or you can have different properties like `List<Club> Clubs` and `List<BirthdayClub> BirthdayClubs` or you can use inheritance but it's fragile and wont work in all serialization formats, if you do the base class should be abstract.

Comment: Those options make sense. If there are only a fixed number of clubs do you think it could be a good idea to just have singular properties on the `Club` DTO that may or may not be populated (like your `BirthdayClubs` example without the `List<>`)?